# Meraki API and javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am new to javascript.  I am attempting to get information from Cisco Meraki's API using an XMLHttpRequest.  I am not getting back the results that I was hoping to get back, which would be a list of Organizations that we have Meraki devices installed at.  I read somewhere that XMLHttpRequests do not work for cross domain access so if I should be using something else, please let me know.  It is also very possible that I have something wrong in the code that I am not catching.

I have looked at a ton of examples of talking to API but none, that I have found deal with passing a unique API key into the get statement from user input into a form.  I added the console.log()'s at the bottom of the function to make sure that my variables are getting values from the html form that calls this function and they are.

Here are the errors I see in the browser after running the function:

> XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
>   addAdmin.php:62 XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "https://n159.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations".
>   listOrgs @ addAdmin.php:62
>   onclick @ addAdmin.php:43
>   addAdmin.php:62 XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "https://n159.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations".

Here is my code:

```
function listOrgs() {
    var apikey = document.getElementById("apikeyinput").value;
    var shard = document.getElementById("shardinput").value;
    var xhttp, orgData, txt, x, dbParam, fullURL = "";
    fullURL = "https://" + shard + ".meraki.com/api/v0/organizations";
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", fullURL, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-
    Requested-With");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key", apikey);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function writeTable() {
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        orgData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        txt += "<table boarder='1'>";
        for (x in orgData) {
          txt += "<tr><td>" + orgData[x].name + "</td></tr>";
          txt += "<tr><td>" + orgData[x].id + "</td></tr>";
        };
        txt += "</table>"
        document.getElementById("printOrgs").innerHTML = txt;
      };
    }

    console.log(fullURL);
    console.log(apikey);
    console.log(shard);
    console.log(xhttp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser complaining about `OPTIONS` sounds like the pre-flight request is failing. I've never worked with this API before so I don't know if these will fix it, but here are some general tips...

- Put `onreadystatechange` before `send` so you don't have a race condition.
- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, not a request header, and it takes a url as a parameter, not the word 'content-type'. Remove that.
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is also a response header, remove that and try replacing it with it's request header, counterpart: `Access-Control-Request-Headers` [Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/preflight_request) to see how that works.
- Your `Content-Type` header is telling hte server to expect some JSON data, yet you are not sending it anything, let alone a JSO.

---

Main thing to take away here is, know the difference between a response header and a request header and make sure you know what they mean.

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once.  Thanks for the pointers.  I will give them a try and report back.